# How to get Google provided Android.Resource.Layout references in my Mono for Android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a Mono for Android project that compiles and runs successfully with the following code.  However a copy/paste into a newer project I'm working on results in a compiler error indicating: [appnamespace].Android.Resource.Layout does not contain a definition for 'SimpleListItem2'.

I'd expect that error if I was trying to access an xml resource layout I defined, but I'm trying to access the default ones provided by Google, specifically 'SimpleListItem2'.  Is there something I need to do get the compiler to recognize the default layouts?  Thanks!

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  View v = convertView;
  if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    v = li.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);
  }

  TextView tt = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
  if (tt != null) { tt.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName); }  
  return v;
}
```

Basically, I'm looking for access to these layouts in the Mono.Android assembly, under the Android.Resource.Layout namespace:

ActivityListItem 
BrowserLInkContextHeader 
ExpandableListContent 
PreferenceCategory 
SelectDialogItem 
SelectDialogMultiChoice 
SelectDialogSingleChoice 
SimpleDropDownItem1Line 
SimpleExpandableListItem1 
SimpleExpandableListItem2 
SimpleGalleryItem 
SimpleListItem1 
SimpleListItem2 
SimpleListItemChecked 
SimpleListItemMultipleChoice 
SimpleListItemSingleChoice 
SimpleListItemDropDownItem 
SimpleSpinnerItem 
TestListItem 
TwoLineListItem

Answer (score 9):

This is a C# language feature, and is behaving as per the C# language specification.

Consider this example:

```
using System;

namespace Example {
    namespace System {
    }

    class Bad : System.Object {
    }
}
```

The above fails to compile:

```
ns.cs(8,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Object' does not exist in 
the namespace `Example.System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

This is true for both .NET CSC and Mono's mcs compilers.

Why? See §10.8 Namespace and type names of the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), pages 100-102.

> - Otherwise, the *namespace-or-type-name* is of the form `N.I` or of the form `N.I<A1, ..., AK>`.
>     `N` is first resolved as a *namespace-or-type-name*.

In this case we're processing `System.Object`, which is of the form `N.I`. So
we need to first resolve `System`:

> - Otherwise, if the *namespace-or-type-name* is of the form `I` or of the form `I<A1, ..., AK>`:
>     ...
>
>   - Otherwise, for each namespace N, starting with the namespace in which the
>       namespace-or-type-name occurs, continuing with each enclosing namespace
>       (if any), and ending with the global namespace, the following steps are evaluated
>       until an entity is located:
>       ...

This resolves the token `System` to `Example.System`. Now that `System` is
resolved the compiler attempts to resolve `System.Object`, i.e. the fully
qualified name of `Example.System.Object`. This type does not exist, and we get
an error.

The fix for the above sample? Use `global::`:

```
class Bad : global::System.Object {
}
```

The same is true for your Android code; if you happen to be within an
`Example.Android` namespace and you need to use the `Android.Resource.Layout`
type, then use `global::Android.Resource.Layout`.

Or you can use a *using-alias*, which is resolved at the point of declaration, allowing:

```
using System;
using MyObject = System.Object;

namespace Example {
    namespace System {
    }

    class Bad : MyObject {
    }
}
```

Comment: `global::Android.Resource.Layout` <- excellent solution, with thorough explanation.  Wish I could + more than 1.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that namespace collisions causes this error. Be warned when using "Android" in your namespace.

If the app's namespace includes "Android", Xamarin's Mono for Android compiler seems to struggle resolving Google's SimpleListItem2 object.

To experience the error, the "Android" string needs to be a complete string (not substring) in the namespace.  The namespace "BenHorgen.Android.MyApps.TestApp" **will** cause the compiler error.

More specifically, including the string "Android" as substring in the namespace will **not** cause the issue.  For example:  "BenHorgen.MyAndroidApps.TestApp" does not cause the problem for me.

Comment: Same effect here. Did you file a bug or something?

Comment: Make sure no other project (shared/library) is using android in its namespace. For example I used XYZ.Common.Android as the name of a common library... OOOOPS.

Comment: I did not file a bug because it appears to be valid behavior from the .NET compilers/preprocessors. The compiler will assume scope based on the namespace. If a project demands the use of "Android" in the namespace, you can overcome the compiler exception by fully qualifying the namespace for all objects within the Google Android SDK.